# which zmq pattern can I use for router communications?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, zeromq, pyzmq

I want to connect peer-to-peer by TCP. With which zmq pattern I can connect them? Does I need server/ client for each side?

Answer (score 0):

You can use several patterns for p2p.

Here is socket features in brief:

1. **REQ-REP** sync pair of sockets. **pros:** doesn't drop messages when [HWM](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#High-Water-Marks) is reached. **cons:** this pair of sockets is sync and blocking, it means that if REQ socket sent a message, it will wait for a reply forever and there is no reply, you can use it again only after recreating.
2. **DEALER-ROUTER** async pair of sockets. **pros:** these socket are not blocking and you can route your messages, but **cons:** it HWM of ROUTER socket is reached it will drop messages and there is no API to let you know about it.
3. **PUSH-PULL** async pair of sockets. **pros:** no blocks, no message drops, async, **cons:** no routing, so its ideal for p2p, but if you have 1-to-N connection all messages will be distributed by round robin

If you have N-to-N or your peers come and go and you have no discovery service, you may use any pattern with broker (but you must implement broker by yourself, its not very hard to do).

Here is [The Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all), you can find a lot of examples on python there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I used publish/subscriber for each router